# How to retrieve values for a vscode extension from other extension which is defined in extension Dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am planning to write two VS Code extensions. Extension - 1 has sharing data and from Extension -2, I want to read those keys/values. For this, I am defining in Extension -1 to set a value like this

- context.globalState.update("key", value);

and I am retrieving this in Extension -2 like this

- context.globalState.get("key"); // This is giving me undefined

Is there any way to get the values from parent extension to child?

Comment: define a command in ext-1 to get a key and call this command in ext-2 with the name of the key as argument

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you give me one example, to call a command from ext-2?

Comment: the same as you call any VSC command from an extension